# Firebug shows more <div>'s than I see in source code

Tags: html, css, firebug

I have a large HTML page, which includes many CSS files.

When I try to debug that HTML page with Firebug, it shows more `<div>`s than what I see in source code. Also, there are some tags that are greyed out. In the pictures what is underlined with green color are elements that don't exist in the source code.

Why is that? Is it because CSS files are "including" those "new" `<div>`s?

I've never seen that CSS files can insert `<div>`s or `<a>`s into an HTML page.

[image: HTML structure including elements not coming from source code]

[image: HTML source code on the server side]

Source code edited with Notepad:

[image: Source code edited with Notepad]

Comment: click the "+" signs near all the divs in your IDE. Your code is collapsed for readability.

Comment: A lot of times, partial pages are loaded into main pages (like a layout page).

Comment: It's not that. For example, ´<div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width:100%;">´ does not "exists" in source code

Comment: You can't make divs with CSS, but you can with Javascript. Would that explain what happens?

Comment: That's it. It was a javascript effect. Sorry if this was a dumb question, but if haven't asked it, I'd never know . Should I delete it?

Comment: You could remove the script that is creating that div or modify it.

Comment: What you see in firebug is actually not the source, but the DOM representation. Greyed out parts in it are made invisible by CSS and thus represented like that as visual indication.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug does not change your HTML, nor does CSS add `<div>`s (though it can create [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) like e.g. [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)).

If the additional elements are not included in your HTML output, they must be created dynamically through a JavaScript on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any libraries? If so, which ones are you using? Sometimes libraries add elements to perform whatever actions they were created to do.

Answer (score 0):

These elements that you can see here, is the added elements by either JavaScript or any other library based on Javascript.

Ex:

suppose we have a div in HTML like this

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

and we have written a code,

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#example').html('<p>example html</p>')
});
</script>
```

Then in this case if you check the source code you will get.

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

and if you check the same page using Firebug or Inspect Element you will get

```
<div id="example"><p>example html</p></div>
```

Hope its clear now.